# JavaScript: Object inheriting from Function.prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I was testing out James Shore's [Object Playground](http://www.objectplayground.com/), and I see that all methods inherit from Function.prototype, including the methods on the global Object.prototype. How does that work? Isn't that kinda circular? I mean... doesn't the Function.prototype "itself" inherent from the Object.prototype? So how does Object inherent anything from Function.prototype? Isn't a function only a sub-type of Object? Shouldn't Object inherently contain these behaviors anyway? Why the need for that inheritance?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### TL;DR

**Object.prototype** is last in the prototype chain and it doesn't inherit from anything. The **Object** constructor is the one that inherits from **Function.prototype** because it's just a function; it's a *Function* instance.

---

### Long Version

Since your question is a general one, I'll try to describe a few subjects and hopefully you will answer your own question. Here are the subjects I'll try to cover:

1. Two ways to use the word "prototype".
2. How classes are created in JavaScript.
3. How the **Function** & **Object** constructors relate.

***Note:** It can be hard and at times confusing to explain how JavaScript really works. I hope that you'll get something out of it though.*

### Two ways to use the word "prototype"

The word "prototype" can be a little confusing in JavaScript. That's because there are at least two ways to use this word depending on the context:

**1)** *"The **prototype object** of another object"*

The prototype object of another object is also talked about as the *"internal prototype"*, denoted as *[[Prototype]]*, or `__proto__`; they all mean the same thing. As an example let's take this array: `nums = [9, 8, 7];`. We say that `nums` is an array... but why?

1. We say it's an array because it is an instance of the `Array` constructor (*constructors are just functions, except we use them with the **new** keyword*).
2. We also say it's an array because *its* prototype object (*a.k.a. "internal prototype"*) is the object contained inside of the `Array.prototype` property.

**2)** *"The **prototype property** of a constructor function"*

Continuing with the `nums` array example, the Array constructor function has a property named `prototype`, and we can access it like this: `Array.prototype`. This property is the "internal prototype" of Array instances, and provides all the methods that we're used to calling on arrays - e.g. `forEach`, `push`, `pop`, `join`, and so on.

So, along the same lines, the internal prototype of my function `foo()`, or any other function, is the object that's contained inside of the `Function.prototype` property; in other words, `Function.prototype` is any function's "internal prototype" object. Also, we can say that the *Function* constructor has a *prototype* property, which eventually is the "internal prototype" of all functions.

Where I'm getting at is that we speak of one thing (the *prototype*) in two different ways. In the first way we say: "the prototype/internal prototype" of an object, and in the second way we say: "the constructor's prototype" property.

### How classes are created in JavaScript

In JavaScript **constructor functions** are like **classes** in other programming languages. Well, not quite. Actually, to resemble classes, JavaScript uses a combination of a *constructor function* and another object called the **prototype**. Actually every JavaScript function acquires a *prototype* property automatically because a function can be used as a constructor or simply as a function. When a function isn't used as a constructor, its *prototype* property isn't used for anything and it's just dangling there as a useless property.

In classical languages, the class contains both the *instance variables* and the *instance methods*, however in JavaScript, the constructor function contains the instance variables and its *prototype* object contains the instance methods.

Instance variables are unique to the particular instance of a constructor function (*they contain instance specific data*), and instance methods are shared by all instances. In other words, all instances can execute the instance methods but cannot access the variables of each other.

So, all objects in JavaScript are instances of their respective constructor functions. For example, an array such as `[1,2,3]` is an instance of the `function Array() {}` constructor. Objects such as `{key: 'value'}` are instances of the `function Object() {}` constructor. JavaScript functions such as `alert()` are instances of the `function Function() {}` constructor... and so on.

Again, all constructor functions in JavaScript have a `prototype` property, and this property includes the methods that instances of the constructor will inherit.

**Example:**

```
// Person constructor to create people instances
function Person(name, age) {
  // Every instance has its own "instance variables", a.k.a. properties. 
  this.name = name;
  this.age  = age;
}


// The "instance methods"
Person.prototype = {
  greet: function() {
    return 'Hello ' + this.name;
  },
  //...
};


// Joe is an instance of the `Person` constructor, and Joe's "prototype"
// is the `Person.prototype` object. We call Joe's "prototype" the 
// "internal prototype". 
var joe = new Person('Joe Doe', 44);
joe.name; //=> Joe Doe
joe.greet(); //=> Hello Joe Doe
```

### How the Function & Object constructors relate

The `Object` Constructor.

The **Object** constructor is just like the *Person* constructor above, except it creates object instances instead of person instances.

The `Function` Constructor.

The **Function** constructor is just like the *Person* & *Object* constructors above, except that it creates Function instances, in other words it creates functions.

All constructors in JavaScript like `Person`, `Object`, `Array`, `Function`, `String`, `Boolean`, and so on, are just functions. Since they are functions, it means that they were created with `new Function` internally in the language, and all function methods like `call()` and `apply()` come from **Function.prototype**. In other words, *Function.prototype* is the "prototype/internal prototype" object of all functions, including constructors and the function `Function` itself.

**Conclusion:**

Don't confuse a constructor's `prototype` property, which includes the methods that future instances will use, with the internal prototype of the constructor itself.

However, keep in mind that a constructor's `prototype` property is the  internal [[Prototype]] of that constructor's instances. For example, `Function.prototype` is the internal [[Prototype]] for the `Object` constructor, and that makes sense since the `Object` constructor is just another function (a `Function` instance).

For a code conclusion take a look at how the Object & Function constructors  are created internally in JavaScript:

```
// Object constructor
// ==============================================
function Object() { /* ... */ }
// Object.keys()
// Object.observe()
// ...


// `Object.__proto__` (internal [[Prototype]])
// -----------------------------------------------
// Since `Object` is a function, it inherits all of Function's 
// instance methods (the ones inside of Function.prototype). 
// 
// In other words the `Object` constructor can use methods 
// like `apply()`, `call()`, `bind()`, and more.
// 
// So we can say that the Object's prototype is the 
// `Function.prototype` object.
Object.__proto__ = Function.prototype;


// `Object.prototype` (instance methods)
// -----------------------------------------------
// The Object's `prototype` property is totally different from  
// the `__proto__` property. This `prototype` property includes 
// methods that all JavaScript objects inherit. So an object
// literal like `var obj = {}` or an array like `var arr = []` 
// or even a function like `alert` can use these methods.
Object.prototype = {
  constructor: Object,
  hasOwnProperty: function() {},
  isPrototypeOf: function() {},
  //...
};



// Function constructor
// ==============================================
function Function() { /* ... */ }
// Function.call()
// Function.apply()
// ...


// [[Prototype]]  +  instance methods
// -----------------------------------------------
// Since `Function` is a function itself and at the same time 
// the constructor for other JavaScript functions, its internal
// [[Prototype]] and the `prototype` property point to the same 
// exact object.
Function.__proto__ = Function.prototype = {
  apply: function() {},
  call: function() {},
  bind: function() {},

  //...

  // Just an object literal, so it inherits the 
  // Object's instance methods.
  __proto__: Object.prototype
};
```

---

### Further Resources

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#Determining_instance_relationships
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto
- https://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4
- http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es5.1-final.html#sec-15.3.2.1; *A prototype property is automatically created for every function, to provide for the possibility that the function will be used as a constructor.*
- [https://www.quora.com/In-JavaScript-what-is-the-logic-behind-the-data-structure-of-function-prototype-**proto**-and-constructor?share=1](https://www.quora.com/In-JavaScript-what-is-the-logic-behind-the-data-structure-of-function-prototype-__proto__-and-constructor?share=1)

Comment: Where can I read more about the distinction you're making regarding prototypes?

Comment: I have added a few helpful links but generally this understanding comes with more practicing and experience; it takes sometime but eventually it will "click".

Answer (score 1):

## What are Prototypes?

JavaScript is a prototype-based language. Which means that technically there are no "classes". There are just prototypes, which describes objects. Every object has a prototype. The prototype itself, is in fact an object. (Confusing huh? Don't think too hard about it, if you can't wrap your head around it. It will *click* sometime. Just know that prototypes are objects that you can modify).

*Before we continue, I'd like to note that my code samples here does not follow proper or best practices. The code samples I have written is purely to demonstrate or to explain a concept.*

Let's look at some code:

```
Object.toString();                 // "[object Object]"
Object.prototype.toString();       // "[object Object]"
Object.hasOwnProperty('toString'); // true
typeof Object;                     // "function"
typeof Object.prototype            // "object"

var obj = new Object();
obj.toString();                    // "[object Object]"
obj.hasOwnProperty('toString');    // false

obj.toString = function() {
    return 'My Object';
};

obj.toString();                    // "My Object"
obj.hasOwnProperty('toString')     // true
obj.__proto__.toString();          // "[object Object]"
typeof obj;                        // "object"
typeof obj.__proto__;              // "object"
```

You may have also noticed that `typeof Object` returns `"function"`. This is because Object is actually a constructor method, to instantiate new objects. My instance object is actually `typeof obj === "object"`.

## The Prototype Chain

As you see in the above code, `Object` contains a method named `toString`. But instances of `Object` does not. `obj` does not have its own `toString` method. But you can still call `toString` on `obj`. JavaScript does its *inheritance* by following its *prototype chain*.

I could overwrite `obj.toString` to give `obj` its own `toString` method, but `obj.__proto__` property still have the original `toString` method from its `prototype`.

If the object in question does not contain its own property `toString`, then the property will look at its prototype. If its own prototype does not contain the property `toString`, then the lookup will continue up the prototype chain until the property is found. If the prototype is `null`, then that is when a property is `undefined`.

## Everything in JavaScript is an Object?

Yes, down at the very core, eventually in the prototype chain, every object is a JavaScript object. Including `Functions`.

```
var func = function() {};
func.__proto__                       //function Empty() {}
func.__proto__.__proto__             // Object {}
func.__proto__.isPrototypeOf(Object) // true
```

So a function is an object in JavaScript. That is why you can attach properties to functions.

## And some clarification...

> all methods inherit from Function.prototype

No, all methods do not inherit from `Function`. Methods *are* `Function`.

> So how does Object.prototype inherent anything from Function.prototype?

Object does not inherit anything from Function. Object may **use** Function, e.g the `toString` method.

The `Object` kinda demonstrates the *composite* design pattern. (With the exception that it is possible to add properties to an object that reference itself and/or create circular references)

From [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern ]

> In software engineering, the composite pattern is a partitioning design pattern. The composite pattern describes that a group of objects is to be treated in the same way as a single instance of an object. The intent of a composite is to "compose" objects into tree structures to represent part-whole hierarchies.

Because `Object` contains several properties, which are all also `Object`.

So is it loopy? No, not really. But it definitely is recursive.

You can read more about JavaScript prototypes here: http://blog.pluralsight.com/understanding-javascript-prototypes

Note that ES6 is introducing actual classes in JavaScript. That is different from everything I explained above. ES6 `class` is something I have not yet played around with.