# Can anyone explain Object and Function hierarchy in JavaScript ? As in JavaScript everything is inherited from Object

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(Object instanceof Function); //true
console.log(Function instanceof Object); //true
```

Inside JavaScript if `Object` and `Function` are both defined as functions then what is their relation to each other and how are both instances of each other?

I don't understand if Object is at the top most position in JavaScript and how Function also inherits from Object..

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813074/javascript-object-inheriting-from-function-prototype

Comment: "*they both are instanceof of each other*" - not interesting. `Function` is an instance of itself, now take that! (And ordinarily, every function is also an object)

Comment: @Bergi thanks for reply

Comment: From my professor's slides: "Function objects are linked to Function.prototype (which is itself linked to Object.prototype)"

http://cit.dixie.edu/cs/4010/functions.pdf
And
http://cit.dixie.edu/cs/4010/objects.pdf

Comment: One of the best resources I have found for these types of questions is David Herman's Effective JavaScript.  It's the one reference I go back to the most.

Comment: `Object` is not an ordinary object, it's a function. Specifically it's a constructor function for ordinary objects. Since `Object` is a function, `Object instance of Function` is true. An ordinary object is not a function, and so `{} instanceof Function` would be false.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be getting confused between the *value* `Object` and objects in general. You may be thinking from what you see above that this means that "all objects are functions" but this is not true.

All functions are objects. The *values* `Object` and `Function` are both (constructor) functions, so they are both objects as well. In other words, they are both instances of `Object` and `Function`.

Perhaps you'll find this a bit more illuminating:

```js
console.log(Object instanceof Function);         // true
console.log(Function instanceof Function);       // true

console.log(Object instanceof Object);           // true
console.log(Function instanceof Object);         // true

console.log(new Object() instanceof Function);   // false
console.log({} instanceof Function);             // false
console.log(new Function() instanceof Function); // true
console.log(function(){ }  instanceof Function); // true

console.log(new Object() instanceof Object);     // true
console.log({} instanceof Object);               // true
console.log(new Function() instanceof Object);   // true
console.log(function(){ }  instanceof Object);   // true
```